# System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

i'm using code first approach and i know i shouldn't have this much code in my controller any way i keep receiving this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

inner exception would be this

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces,

this is my code

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(Models.Users model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var Ref_DB = new MainDBContext())
            {
                var encryptedPassword = CustomLibraries.CustomEncrypt.Encrypt(model.Password);
                var user = Ref_DB.Users.Create();//this is where error occours
                user.Email = model.Email;
                user.Password = encryptedPassword;
                user.Country = model.Country;
                user.Name = model.Name;
                Ref_DB.Users.Add(user);
                Ref_DB.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "One or more feilds have been errors");            
        }
        return View();
```

i realized my connection string might be the problem it's my connection string

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection"  connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

the .mdf file is in my App_Data folder

and this is my model

```
 public class MainDBContext:DbContext
{
    public MainDBContext()
        :base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Models.Users> Users { get; set; }
}
```

this is user class

```
 public class Users
{
    #region [- Ctor -]
    public Users()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region [- Email -]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region [- PassWord -]
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post our Users class here?

Comment: You'll have to look at details of ModelValidationException. It is possible that the real issue is being hidden. Users.Create() is just triggering model building which is throwing the exception, it can also be the case that the problem is in some other class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,your connection string is Wrong.You have to attache `mdf` file is like this `\MyDatabase.mdf`.

***Complete connection string :***

```
<add name="DefaultConnection"  connectionString="Data Source=
(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated 
Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**Update :**

**use this :**

```
var user = new Models.Users();
```

*Instead of this :*

```
var user = Ref_DB.Users.Create();//this is where error occurs
```

**Update 2 :**

Run below command on your `cmd prompt`

> sqllocaldb create "v12.0"

You have to change the directory to your installation like this :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn>sqllocaldb create "v12.0"
```

**Update 3 :**

[**Breaking Changes to LocalDB**](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2014_0010.htm)

Comment: what is going to do here `var user = Ref_DB.Users.Create();` ?

Comment: i'm creating the Users table within the code base so we can modify it.

Comment: Please see the **Update**.

Comment: the same error happens here `Ref_DB.Users.Add(user);`

Comment: what is your `SQL server` version?

Comment: do you have this too on your inner exception `provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation` ?

Comment: can you put whole `inner exception` ?

Comment: error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Comment: the hole inner exception >>{"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.\r\n)"}

Comment: please see the **Update 2**

Comment: how can i find `cmd promp`?

Comment: on your `run` window,type `cmd` and enter.It's a `Dos` prompt.

Comment: Yes,of course and please see the **Update 3** also.

Comment: this is what happened`>cmd
>sqllocaldb create "v12.0"
Command "sqllocaldb" is not valid.`

Comment: did you see the **Update 3** ?

Comment: please see **Update 2**  also.